# Adding labels to a dataset in tensorflow by using a second dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-processing

Tensorflow beginner here.

My data is split into two csv files, `a.csv` and `b.csv`, relating to two different events `a` and `b`. Both files contain information on the users concerned and, in particular, they both have a `user_id` field that I can use to merge the data sets.

I want to train a model to predict the probability of `b` happening based on the features of `a`. For doing this, I need to append a label column 'has_b_happened' to the data `A` retrieved from `a.csv`. In scala spark, I would do something like:

```
val joined = A
    .join(B.groupBy("user_id").count, A("user_id") === B("user_id"), "left_outer")
    .withColumn("has_b_happened", col("count").isNotNull.cast("double"))
```

In tensorflow, however, I haven't found anything comparable to spark's join. Is there a way of achieving the same result or am I trying to use the wrong tool for it?

Comment: You might get help from documentation that posted in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/datasets_quickstart)

Comment: Hi @Dinusha Dilanka, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I had already read that page and I couldn't find anything addressing my issue.

Comment: If you want to use spark with python you can use Pyspark to perform operation like you did with Scala.

Comment: That might be a solution. Do you know if it is possible to convert a spark dataset to a tensorflow tensor?

Comment: You can try on this `tf.constant(dataframe, dtype = tf.float32)`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying but it's not as simple as that. An error is returned: `Failed to convert object of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> to Tensor`. I will try to work around it and if I manage to solve it I will update you. Thank you for your help.